# Table-valued function out parameters list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need list of parameters which is not in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS`, in `sys.parameters` and in `sys.all_parameters` too.

I need table-valued functions out parameters, that is returned after SELECT -ing from result.

For ex.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetStudentsList] (@groupId INT)
RETURN TABLE
RETURN
  SELECT [Id], [FirstName], [LastName]
  FROM [dbo].[Students];
```

I need to get list of these OUT type parameters: Id, FirstName, LastName. I need just T-SQL script.

Can somebody help? Thanks

Comment: There are no `OUT` parameters at this function. What you describe is just the result of the query performed by the function.

Comment: But, I can get OUT parameters of Scalar-valued function using script: SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER_MODE = 'OUT'; also, Entity Framework can understand, what type is these OUT parameters - how? :)

Comment: Sure, and that also applies to table-valued functions. Scalar-values functions also report their return value in that view in addition to parameters. But the problem is that your function does **NOT** contain any `OUT` parameter, just a single `IN` one (`@groupId`). Neither of this should be of any importance when using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Multi-statement Table-valued function.
Try this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetStudentsList] (@groupId INT)
RETURNS 
@ReturnTable TABLE 
(
    ID INT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(MAX),
    LastName VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Fill the table variable with the rows for your result set
    INSERT INTO @ReturnTable
    SELECT [Id], [FirstName], [LastName]
    FROM [dbo].[Students];
    RETURN 
END
GO
```

Then you can call the function by passing the @groupId;

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[GetStudentsList](@groupId)
```

Comment: But, I need not editing my functions and I'm not talking about specific function. I'm working on project like Entity Framework and need to get list of procedures and functions parameters. I just need a list of table-valued functions OUT parameters - I need script, which gives me that.. Thanks for your answer.